# Excel, how to count software choice per job type?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have software use data for a bunch of different job types. Some people filled in multiple software packages.

My Excel sheet looks like this:
[image]

How do I get the amount of use for each software package per job type?
So for example:

```
           3DS Max AutoCAD Bentley etc...
Architect  2       20      1
Consultant 3       15      3
etc...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in Excel or Google Sheets? You can use a Pivot Table in Excel to get this.

Comment: Google Sheets is off-topic here, on-topic on WebApps.  It isn't identical to Excel in terms of features or how it handles things.  Solutions for one won't necessarily work on the other, and people waste time trying to figure out why good solutions don't work.  Post on the site that is appropriate for your application, and tag with just the correct application.  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'll change my answer to just Excel to avoid confusion